# How to remove b and \n from variable/text file in Python3? (TypeError)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This gives me a massive headache. My code:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("php /var/scripts/data.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
scriptresponse = proc.stdout.read()
print (scriptresponse)
```

Output:

> b'January\n'

I tried `scriptresponse.replace ('\n', '')` but failed:

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

How to remove `b` and `\n` from `scriptresponse` so the output will look like this:

> January

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `universal_newlines=True` as an argument to the `Popen` call.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> If *universal_newlines* is `True`, the file objects stdin, stdout and stderr are opened as text streams in universal newlines mode, as described above in Frequently Used Arguments, otherwise they are opened as binary streams.

Right now you have a binary string (indicated by the `b`). If you still have the trailing newline, use the `rstrip()` method on the string to remove the trailing characters.